# What are the essential Java packages of Android Application Framework?

Tags: android

This mostly theoretical question regarding Android and Java. I want to know which Java packages are used by Android Application Framework? I could guess maybe most of them. But I want to know those essential packages used by application framework in particular. Thanks!

Comment: I am confused here. Do you mean, what Java packages does the Android Framework rely on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the [Android Package Index](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), you can see the packages that form the Android platform.

Packages from standard Java start with either `java` or `javax`, for example:

- `java.text`
- `java.util`
- `java.util.concurrent`
- `javax.net`
- `javax.net.ssl`
- `javax.security.auth`

There are many more packages than this, so I won't list them all, but refer to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) to see the complete list.